# Deleting all group ID data from json files when the bot leaves the group in Telegram Python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

i have this code::

```
def save_group_data_to_json(group_id, invitation_link):
    try:
        with open('groups.json', 'r') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = {}

    data[str(group_id)] = invitation_link

    with open('groups.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)

def callback_func(update, context):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    new_chat_members = update.effective_message.new_chat_members
    left_chat_member = update.effective_message.left_chat_member
    bot = context.bot
    bot_username = "t_bot"
    if bot_username == bot.username:
        invitation_link = bot.export_chat_invite_link(chat_id)
        save_group_data_to_json(chat_id, invitation_link)
      
    if left_chat_member and left_chat_member.username == bot.username:
        # Remove all data related to the group from JSON files
        remove_group_data_from_json(chat_id)
def remove_group_data_from_json(group_id):
    # List of files that need the group ID removed
    files_to_remove = ['welcome.json', 'leave.json', 'rules.json', 'groups.json',
                       'muted.json', 'settings.json', 'lock.json', 'warns.json',
                       'filters.json', 'cursing.json','channel.json']

    # Remove group data from other files
    for file_name in files_to_remove:
        try:
            with open(file_name, 'r') as json_file:
                data = json.load(json_file)

            if str(group_id) in data:
                del data[str(group_id)]

            with open(file_name, 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(data, json_file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    # Remove group ID from groups.json
    GROUPS_FILE = "groups.json"
    if os.path.exists(GROUPS_FILE):
        try:
            with open(GROUPS_FILE, 'r') as groups_file:
                groups_data = json.load(groups_file)

            group_ids = groups_data.get("group_ids", [])
            if group_id in group_ids:
                group_ids.remove(group_id)

                with open(GROUPS_FILE, 'w') as groups_file:
                    json.dump({"group_ids": group_ids}, groups_file, indent=4)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
```

In the past it worked, I want to make it so that when the bot leaves the group, all mentions of the group in the various json files will be deleted.

I'm trying to make the bot delete all the IDs and details of the group it's leaving.